# Cloudflare page rule to match ports

Tags: port, wildcard, cloudflare

I want to add a page rule that matches all ports opened with the http:// protocol and redirect them to https://

For example I want to redirect:

`http://anything.mydomain.com:1234` to `https://anything.mydomain.com:1234`

How can I do this with page rules? Because: `http://*.mydomain.com/*` doesn't work for ports. 
Right now I configured Always use HTTPS for: `http://*.mydomain.com/*` but the ports are still not redirecting to https.

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a pattern like `http://*.mydomain.com*` instead of `http://*.mydomain.com/*`?

Comment: I tried but Cloudflare doesn't accept http://*.mydomain.com* as a valid rule, you can't add * after the tld, so .com* won't be allowed.

Comment: After a bit of research, it seems CloudFlare doesn't support proxying on all ports (Refer to https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156 and https://community.cloudflare.com/t/point-domain-to-ip-and-port/45006)